# DatePickerDialog not adding days in Date

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using **DatePickerDialog** with some logic around it

Logic like using `if-else` statement

```
if(number == 1) // then add 1 day

else if (number == 2) // then add 3 days
```

**REQUIREMENT:** Using Spinner to select number of days and DatePicker to show that particular date in Dialog

**ISSUE:** The thing is I have selected Item one in spinner (which will add 1 day in dtdob date), now I have selected spinner Item two (which has to add 3 days in dtdob date).... but when I do tap on DatePicker showing the same date in DatePicker (which I got in case of Spinner Item selection 1) not the new ones

For example `dtdob` date is **15 Dec 2015**

Case 1: `First Spinner` Item selected (getting **16 Dec 2015**) - which is totally correct

Case 2: I have chosen `Second Spinner` Item (still getting **16 Dec 2015**) whereas I was expecting **18 Dec 2015**

Code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID1:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog dpDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener1, year1, month1, day1);
            DatePicker datePicker1 = dpDialog1.getDatePicker();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
            c.setTime(dtdob); // this is the date I am getting from somewhere
            if (number == 1) {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            } else if (number == 2) {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
            } else if (number == 3) {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            } else {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            datePicker1.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            return dpDialog1;


    }
    return null;
}
```

**Portion:** Number is being fetched

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View view, int position, long id) {
                number = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: for test case add `if` instead of `else if`

Comment: I haven't tried to reproduce the issue, but I would say make sure that every time a **Spinner** item is selected, the method is invoked. It seems that the method is invoked only the first time.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Given a try getting same issue, I guess its not resetting the DatePicker with new values.... like my dtdob is 18 Dec 2014 and I have chosen spinner Item 1 (which will add 1 day in dtdob date) and its adding and I am getting 19 Dec 2014..... Now I have selected Spinner Item 2 (which has to add 3 days in dtdob date) but whenever I do tap on DatePicker directly showing 19 Dec 2014 whereas I was expecting 21 Dec 2014

Comment: @PranitBankar ok can you show me the way... and for more check my above comment posted to IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @Sophie: Can you post the code where `number` is being fetched?

Comment: @PranitBankar posted please check above Portion: Number is being fetched

Comment: You can try replacing `number = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();` with `number = parent.getSelectedItemPosition(pos);`

Comment: @PranitBankar you can the point

Comment: @PranitBankar getting same result only, like my dtdob is 18 Dec 2014 and I have chosen spinner Item 1 (which will add 1 day in dtdob date) and its adding and I am getting 19 Dec 2014..... Now I have selected Spinner Item 2 (which has to add 3 days in dtdob date) but whenever I do tap on DatePicker directly showing 19 Dec 2014 whereas I was expecting 21 Dec 2014

Comment: @Sophie: The place where you are updating the date, can you add 2 days in the `else` part. Just trying to make sure if 1 is added because of `if (number == 1)` or because of `else`

Comment: @PranitBankar actually main concern is why its showing same date as default date in datepicker .... whatever the spinner item I am selecting very first time... after that whenever I do tap on DatePicker always showing that particular date by default in datepicker ... which is totally wrong :( why datepicker is not behaving like the fresh datepicker in second time (just behaving fresh for the very first time)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the code portion where you define number. Your Date increment code seems fine.

Comment: From the looks of this, the problem is mostly with number.

Comment: posted please check above Portion: Number is being fetched

Comment: this is should be comment .